# Calculating the bounce of the ball

Tags: math, lua, geometry, bounce

I'm working on a breakout game, and I stuck a little with calculating the bounce of the ball from paddle according to where it hit the paddle. I came out with the following `ball.vx = (ball.x - paddle.x) / 10` it bounces, but not equally on both sides of the paddle. for example if ball hit the far left side of the paddle, ball.vx would be -3.2 and if the far right 1.6.

What i did is:
    ball.vy = 4
    ball.vx = (ball.x - paddle.x) / 10

```
ball.x = ball.x + ball.vx
ball.y = ball.y + ball.vy
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "not equally on both sides of the paddle".

Comment: What i mean by that is, for example if ball hit the far left side of the paddle, ball.vx would be -3.2 and if the far right 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the calculation is performed from the same reference on each object instead of e.g. the center of the paddle and the corner of the ball.

(Also, consider using equations that keep the speed the same [or very close] even if the angle changes.)

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind that `ball.x` and `paddle.x` refer to the **left side** of both **ball** and **paddle**.

Assuming that :

- `ball.r` is the **radius** of the ball
- `paddle.w` is the **width** of the paddle

You should try something like that :

<strike>`ball.vx = (ball.x - ball.r/2 - paddle.x - padde.w/2) / 10`</strike>

*update :*

`ball.vx = ((ball.x + ball.width/2) - (paddle.x + padde.w/2)) / 10`

*(`ball.x - ball.r/2` and `paddle.x - padde.w/2` represent the middle of both **ball** and **paddle**)*

Comment: well i don't have radius as the ball is an image, but i did ball.width/2, unfortunately it didn't work out, the ball goes always at right side. ball.vx = (ball.x - ball.width/2 - paddle.x - paddle.width/2) / 10

Comment: I think I made a mistake, try with : 
`ball.vx = ((ball.x + ball.width/2) - (paddle.x + padde.w/2)) / 10`

Comment: Didn't work either. The ball goes in sharp angle to left when hits the far left side of paddle, and moves slightlyin right when hits the far right paddle side.

Comment: weird, do you change the ball.vx value somewhere else ?